# Creating a favourites page by using a session variable

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a Favourites Pages where the user selects items from the "menu" and then the item is placed in the Favourites Page.  I am making use of a session variable

```
$_SESSION['favourites']
```

I am starting the session by using the

> session_start('session.php');

In the session_start it includes

```
<?php 

session_start(); 

?>
```

The favourite feature works when I combine the two files together, but it does not work when I display the favourites on a different page.

This is the menu page

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "restaurant");
$sql= "SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY id ASC";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultcheck=mysqli_num_rows($result);


if(isset($_POST["add_to_favourite"]))
{
    if(isset($_POST["favourites"])) 
    {
        $food_item_id = array_column($_SESSION["favourites"], "item_id");
            if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $food_item_id))
            {
                $count = count($_SESSION["favourites"]);
                $item_array = array(
                    'item_id' => $_GET["id"],
                    'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                    'item_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                    'item_desc' => $_POST["hidden_desc"]
                );
                $_SESSION["favourites"][$count] = $item_array;
            }else{
                echo '<script>alert(You have already added this item to Favourites")</script>';
            }
        }
        else{
            $food_array = array(
                'item_id' => $_GET["id"],
                'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                'item_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                'item_desc' => $_POST["hidden_desc"]
            );
            $_SESSION["favourites"][0] = $food_array;
    }
}

?>
<!-- Start of HTML  -->
<section id="intro">
        <div class="hero-global container">
            <h1 class="global-header">Detailed Menu</h1>
        </div>
</section>

<div class="container">
        <ul class="food-cards"> 
<?php
if($resultcheck>0)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
?>
      <li class="card-info">
            <form method="post" action="favourites.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">            
                <div class="food-card">
                    <div class="food-pic">
                        <img src="./assets/english-breakfast.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="food-cont">
                        <h2 class="food-title">
                            <?php 
                                echo $row['name']
                            ?>
                        </h2>
                        <p class="food-desc"> 
                            <?php echo $row["description"]; ?> 
                        </p>
                        <div class="price-fav-btn">
                            <div class="price"> 
                                <?php
                                    echo "€".$row['price']
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="atf-btn">
                                <input class="fav-btn" type="submit" name="add_to_favourite" value="Add to Favourites"/>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_desc" value="<?php echo $row["description"]; ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
         </li>
    <?php
    }
}
?>

    </ul> <!-- end of ul list -->
</div>
```

This is the favourites page, where the items are displayed.

```
<?php 

        if(isset($_GET["action"]))
        {
            if($_GET["action"] == "delete")
            {
                foreach($_SESSION["favourites"] as $keys => $values)
                {
                    if($values["item_id"] == $_GET["id"])
                    {
                        unset($_SESSION["favourites"][$keys]);
                        echo '<script>alert("Item Removed")</script>';
                        echo '<script>window.location="menudetails.php"</script>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
?> 
<div><h1>Favourites</h1></div>

<table>
    <tr style="text-align: left">
        <th width="30%">Name</th>
        <th width="60%">Description</th>
        <th width="5%">Price</th>
        <th width="5%">Remove</th>
    </tr>
<?php 

    if(!empty($_SESSION["favourites"]))
    {
        foreach($_SESSION["favourites"] as $key => $value)
        {
        
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td width: 20%><?php echo $value["item_name"] ?></td>
                <td style="text-align: left"><?php echo $value["item_desc"]?></td>
                <td><?php echo '€'.$value["item_price"]?></td>
                <td><a href="favourites.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $value["item_id"]; ?>"><span class="fav-btn">Remove</span></a></td>
            </tr>
        

        
            <tr>
        </table>

        

            <?php
        }
    }

            ?>
```

EDIT:

I am starting the session on both pages.

Also, the part that is not working is when it comes to seeing whats in the favourites page. There is not output, only the link (in search bar) with the  respective id.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KbAA.png)

Comment: You have to put session_start() in both pages. It's not quite clear if you've done that or not? You didn't expand on "doesn't work" so it's not clear if you have a specific error message, or some other unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Why did you delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67684953/display-last-element-in-list-prolog/67685118#67685118 ?