# Display Last Element in List Prolog

Tags: prolog

Given the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, display the last element. I am using only one parameter and using recursion.

This is what I tried. But the output is always `true`.

```
lastElement([]).

lastElement(Stack).

lastElement([_|Tail], Head):-
    lastElement(Tail, Head).
```

The output I am getting is

```
> lastElement([1,2,3,4,5]). Singleton variables: [Stack] true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you over thought this.

The predicate `lastElement(Stack).` will match on everything. You just want the last element of the list.

Try this:

```
lastElement([Head]) :- write(Head).
lastElement([_|Tail]):-
    lastElement(Tail).
```

When I run `?- lastElement([1,2,3]).` I get `3` displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didnt realise I deleted this question. I undeleted it now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you also tagged [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog), I just want to add that SWI-Prolog provides the [`last(?List, ?Last)`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=last/2) predicate "out of the box".

```
?- last([1,2,3], X).
X = 3.

?- last(L, 5).
L = [5] ;
L = [_13202, 5] ;
L = [_13202, _13862, 5]
...
```